# Bias variance tradeoff KeyError

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression

I want to estimate the bias and variance for a regression model in Python 3. I used the following code:

```
# estimate the bias and variance for a regression model
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from mlxtend.evaluate import bias_variance_decomp

# load dataset
sasw_data = pd.read_csv('3-3.5.csv')

X = sasw_data.drop(columns=['shear wave velocity'])
y = sasw_data['shear wave velocity']

# split the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)
# define the model
model = LinearRegression()
# estimate bias and variance
mse, bias, var = bias_variance_decomp(model, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, loss='mse', num_rounds=200, random_seed=1)
# summarize results
print('MSE: %.3f' % mse)
print('Bias: %.3f' % bias)
print('Variance: %.3f' % var)
```

I also install the mlxtend library. But I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-00754c864589> in <module>
     16 model = LinearRegression()
     17 # estimate bias and variance
---> 18 mse, bias, var = bias_variance_decomp(model, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, loss='mse', num_rounds=200, random_seed=1)
     19 # summarize results
     20 print('MSE: %.3f' % mse)

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ 37,  72,  79, 129,  71,  25,  20, 101,  50,  68,\n            ...\n            113,  47,  45,  87,  45, 116,  66,  46, 128,  63],\n           dtype='int64', length=133)] are in the [columns]"
```

Please let me know how to overcome this error.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is because the types of the variables `X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test` are of type `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` or `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.

A simple fix would be to convert these variables to `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`  using the inbuilt `.values` while calling the bias-variance decomposition function.

```
mse, bias, var = bias_variance_decomp(model, X_train.values, y_train.values, 
                                      X_test.values, y_test.values, 
                                      loss='mse', random_seed=1)
```